# Sequelize Timezone settings are not recognized on Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem with my Sequelize configuration. I am trying to set the timezone but it is not working once I upload it to my Ubuntu Server. I find it very strange because it works perfectly fine locally.

```js
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.mysql.database, config.mysql.user, config.mysql.password, config.mysql.port, {
    host: config.mysql.host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        useUTC: false, //for reading from database
        dateStrings: true,
        typeCast: function (field, next) { // for reading from database
            if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
              return field.string()
            }
            return next()
        },
    },
    timezone: '-07:00',
    define: {
      timestamps: false
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    }
  })
```

I checked everything I can think of and still cannot find the issue.

My server has the correct timezone and the MySQL server is using the system timezone, set they are on the same setting. When insert data into the tables manually via command line it has the correct date and time. However, anything I do through Sequelize is always entered and returned in UTC with one exception, when I use a raw query, the time is exactly as entered into the server.

Any help with this mystery would be greatly appreciated.